# How do I keep a transparent view controller loaded overtop of all my other view controllers?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

So I'm creating a game for the iPhone, and I want to have a transparent view controller loaded at all times, that goes overtop of all my other view controllers. This transparent view controller would display things such as the in game time, current money, etc., at the top of every view. I want to do it this way so that all the code for the clock timer can be kept in one file and won't need to be copy/pasted into all my different OtherViewController.m files. I have researched for a while now, but I can't seem to figure out how to create this view controller without blocking out the one behind it, or without it being blocked out when I transition to a new view. Any suggestions on how to do this as well as possible alternate solutions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this with a custom container controller. This controller would have a transparent view at the top, and the content view controllers would be shown underneath this transparent view. You could do this in IB with container views. Start with a regular UIViewController and add a transparent UIView at the top with whatever subviews you want. Then, add a container view, and make it the size of the whole screen. In the scene list on the left, you then have to move the container view up so it's the first one in the main view's subviews list (this will put the transparent view on top). You could embed the contained controller that you get with the container view in a navigation controller (with the nav bar turned off), and then add you other controllers from there.

[image]

[image]

I've colored the transparent view blue in the image so you can see it -- the container view extends up underneath it to the status bar. As you navigate to different controllers, they will slide in underneath the transparent view, which will remain stationary.

Comment: This seems to me like the best solution. I've tried it out and I think this will work! Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the view controller as a child of the root view controller and add its view as a subview. You'll need to do some tampering with `hitTest` to ensure that touches get passed on to the sibling views.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use inheritance to build a parent view controller that is used by all your other controllers - if you do this maybe you don't need a transparent view covering the whole visible area, but you could add items like time/score/HUD as required - and move them around depending on which view you are in. To use two completely contrived examples, in a flying part of your game you might want all this information at the top of the screen covering only sky, but if you are in a duck shooting part of the game the information should be displayed at the bottom of the screen so you don't hide the ducks.

I would start by experimenting with a base class view controller that draws views in `viewDidLoad:`